# c# Sorting a object list by combination of three values in the same object

Tags: c#-4.0

```
List<string[]> travelerList = new List<string[]>();
string[] traveler1 = {"c","3","b"};
string[] traveler2 = {"a","1","d"};
string[] traveler3 = {"d","4","a"};
string[] traveler4 = {"b","2","c"};
travelerList.Add(traveler1);
travelerList.Add(traveler2);
travelerList.Add(traveler3);
travelerList.Add(traveler4);
```

I have three columns in a table in Database which will look like

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
  a       1       d
  b       2       c
  c       3       b
  d       4       a
```

I need to sort the travelerList by combination of above three columns so that after sorting it looks like

```
{"a","1","d"}
{"b","2","c"}
{"c","3","b"}
{"d","4","a"}
```

Comment: I don't get it... Do you get the traveler list from the database? Do you want to sort the traveler list so it looks like the database? It looks like sorting on either the first or the second column, is it any of those, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can guarantee that the `string[]` will *always* have at least 3 elements, you can sort easily enough:

```
travelerList.OrderBy(t => t[0]).ThenBy(t => t[1]).ThenBy(t => t[2])
```

Of course, a strongly-typed object is a bit more secure in the matter than a `string[]`.  Something as simple as:

```
class Traveler
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public string Column3 { get; set; }
}
```

Then if the list is a `List<Traveler>` you could be somewhat safer with:

```
travelerList.OrderBy(t => t.Column1).ThenBy(t => t.Column2).ThenBy(t => t.Column3)
```

You could even take it a step further and define the object to implement `IComparable` so that it internally knows how to compare itself with other instances.  Then you'd just need:

```
travelerList.OrderBy(t => t)
```

This approach would lean more toward object oriented principles, keeping the logic encapsulated within the model so it doesn't need to be repeated by multiple instances of consuming code.

Answer (score 1):

A custom comparator is what you're looking for. [Article Here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sort_using_a_custom_comparator)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this is related to your database since your showing a `List<string[]>`.

However, ignoring that you can use `OrderBy` + `ThenBy`:

```
travelerList = travelerList
    .OrderBy(t => t[0])
    .ThenBy(t => t[1])
    .ThenBy(t => t[2])
    .ToList();
```